# bundle exec rake db:seed only seeds about half of my data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, seeding

I have created an array of hashes in ruby from data I scraped using nokogiri. In one of my keys named [:contributors] I stored another array containing a list of names. I have verified that the data in my data structure is correct and working properly.

I'm trying to seed data from my seeds.rb file to populate my PostgreSQL database, but for some reason it only populates about half of my [:contributors]. Below is the code I used to iterate through my data structure to create the seeded data:

```
@trending_array.each_with_index do |item, index|
  Repository.create(title: item[:title], description: item[:description], language: 
  item[:language])
  item[:contributors].each do |contributor|
    Contributor.create(username: contributor, repository_id: index + 1)
  end
end
```

All of my migrations are working properly, and my model validations are correct. About half of the data seeds properly, and all the associations work, but it always stops after 36qty contributors, out of 115qty total.

Any ideas as to why my whole dataset isn't seeding properly?

Comment: You shouldn't use array index's to set foriegn key identifiers as indexes all start with 0 which means that your code will always fail on the second run. Have a look at my answer for clarification.

Comment: if my answer helped you out you need to accept the answer. You'll find the button to do so on the top left of my answer! Ask if you need any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are assigning the `repository_id` is incorrect. What happens when you run this function a second time? The index field will always start at 0. So your code will always look for a Repository with an id of 1.

So everytime you run this script, even though it's creating new repositories. The contributors are being assigned to the same Repositories. And if you have deleted those first 115 Repository records then your Contributor will not get created (as it will try find the repository with id 1).

Assuming your associations are correct (Repository has_many Contributors)

## How to fix it?

#### Step 1.) You don't need to declare the index, as the index will always start at 0, so it's not very good or useful for using to set identifiers.

```
@trending_array.each do |item|
```

#### Step 2.) Store your created repository into a variable. Makes it easier to manipulate and update later

```
repository = Repository.create(title: item[:title], description: item[:description], language: item[:language])
```

#### Step 3.) Use your newly created repository variable to create children contributors.

```
repository.contributors.create(username: contributor)
```

This way there is no need for id's as you are explicity using the repository that you just created to create contributors for that record.

Your new block should look like:

```
@trending_array.each do |item|
  repository = Repository.create(title: item[:title], description: item[:description], language: item[:language])
  item[:contributors].each do |contributor|
    repository.contributors.create(username: contributor)
  end
end
```

Comment: Great advice! Thanks--I realized there were some conflicts on my validations that prevented the process from iterating through every item in my array. With no validations, it worked properly, but it's definitely best practice to implement that block as you suggested, and still use model validations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Repository.create!` and `Contributor.create!` instead of the none-bang version, so if there is an error it will be raised and you will get a message for the error.

mostly I think may be the validations of the `Contributor` model are not passing, or the `index+1` is not resulting in a valid `repository_id`.

the non bang version does not raise and error and it just returns `false` or the created record if it was created successfully.